# Function overloading in C++ with int and int64_t. Ambiguous match with "1LL"

Tags: c++, overloading

```
#include <iostream>
void hi(int x) {
    std::cout << "hi\n";
}
void hi(int64_t y) {
    std::cout << "hi2\n";
}
int main() {
    hi(3LL);
}
```

Why does it throw ambiguous match? I think it should resolves to the second function since it's an exact match. Or is int64_t a different type from 3LL?

It seems that the error only occurs on some compiler, namely g++ but not clang. Not sure if it is caused by different compiler flags or version used though.

Comment: One is `long long`, the other int64_t`. It may well be implementation-defined, but check e.g. cppreference.com for the precise definitions. BTW: Could you include the compiler call and the whole output, just to make it easier to cluster similar errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or is int64_t a different type from 3LL?

Yes, `int64_t` is `long` (in this implementation). `3LL` is `long long`.

Modern IDE have a "go to definition" feature, where you can position your cursor over `int64_t` and go to https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/bits/stdint-intn.h#L27 and then go to https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/posix/bits/types.h#L43 .